# Proof that four-potential is a four-vector

Tags: electromagnetism, special-relativity

My teacher proposed this "simple" proof that the 4-potential is a 4-vector which I am very skeptic about.

Since under gauge transformation the 4-four potential transforms as
$$
A^\mu \mapsto A^\mu + \partial^\mu\lambda,
$$
$\lambda$ being a scalar function, it follows that $A^\mu$ *must* trasform as a 4-vector under Lorentz transformation, since $\partial^\mu$ is one.

Is he right? What am I missing? I asked him for clarification but didn't get any more information other than this.

Comment: In Weinberg's The Quantum Theory of Fields, Vol I Weinberg states that as the Coulomb gauge has $A^{0}$ vanishing in all Lorentz frames, implies vividly that $A^{\mu}$ cannot be a four-vector.

Comment: @Bacon: Doesn't that just mean that the Coulomb gauge condition isn't covariant?

Comment: We may use the wave equation with sources.But there could be problems:https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BymT8iD6LY1nRDVkbGJXVjBYSlE/view?usp=sharing

Comment: So is the 4-potential a 4-vector just in some choice of the gauge or always?

Comment: Clarification on my last comment:E=0.B=0 does not necessarily imply phi=0,A=0;B=curl A=0 could be true for non zero variable A.[Aharonov Bohm effect].E=0 implies grad phi=-del A/del t without phi or A becoming constant/zero. Therefore four potential=0 in one frame does not necessarily imply such components are zero in all frames.Solutions other than 4 vectors seem to be possible.

Comment: All gauged values of four potential will not be four vectors: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BymT8iD6LY1nbl9jdnh2SkVwVEk/view?usp=sharing

Comment: The wave equation for four potential is deduced by applying Lorentz gauge. Four potential travels with a finite speed --at the speed of light.In that sense it is relativistically consistent.We might expect the four potential to be a four vector.But within the remit of Lorentz gauge we may have other types of gauges. One will be a four vector. Others may not be so.

Comment: A revised version of the paper in my first comment:https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BymT8iD6LY1nS0wxcjRpTldyamc/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 3):

This works perfectly fine, but is more a heuristic.

If $\lambda$ is a scalar function, meaning that $\lambda \mapsto \lambda' = \lambda\circ \Lambda^{-1}$ under a Lorentz transformation $\Lambda$, then $\lambda(x) \mapsto \lambda'(x') = \lambda(\Lambda^{-1}\Lambda x) = \lambda(x)$. Most functions that look as if they are scalars *are* scalars, exceptions usually involve derivatives in some form. In particular $f(x) = x^0$ is a perfectly fine scalar function, even though it is not a Lorentz scalar in the sense that $f(\Lambda x) = f(x)$. It's confusing terminology.

In the same vein, transforming as a four-vector under Lorentz transformations means $A^\mu \mapsto \Lambda_\nu^\mu A'^\nu$ (note again the prime, standing for $A' = A\circ\Lambda^{-1}$), or $A\mapsto \Lambda\circ A\circ \Lambda^{-1}$, since then $A^\mu(x) \mapsto \Lambda^\mu_\nu A'^\nu(x') = \Lambda^\mu_\nu A^\nu(x)$ - the point at which you evaluate the function after the transformation still hasn't changed, but the transformation not only changed the way the coordinate is expressed (as $x'$ instead of $x$) but also the basis of your vector space.

So, finally, yes $\partial^\mu \lambda$ is a four-vector if $\lambda$ is a scalar function simply because $\partial^\mu \mapsto \Lambda^\mu_\nu \partial'^\nu$ and $\lambda(x)\mapsto \lambda'(x')$. Since adding two things that are not of the same type is generally not very well-defined, we conclude that $A^\mu$ better be a four-vector if it is to be a meaningful quantity. However, "better be" is not a proof. Formally you have to examine your *definition* of $A^\mu$ and deduce from that that it is a four-vector. How exactly that works depends on whether you cobbled it together from the non-relativistic parts $\phi,\vec A$ or defined it to be the anti-derivative of the field-strength tensor $F$.

Answer (score 2):

Adding a four vector ($\partial^\mu \lambda$) to 4 components ($A^\mu$) does not necessarily mean the four components are a four vector.
The usual proof that $A^\mu$ is a four vector follows from the wave equation
$$\square\, A^\mu=4\pi j^\mu,$$
after using the covariance of the continuity equation to prove that $j^\mu$ is a four vector.

Comment: But is my teacher's answer incomplete o plainly wrong?

Comment: Yes and yes, but don't quote me. He may have said something else that you misinterpreted.

Comment: Applying Lorentz gauge in any one inertial frame we obtain the wave equation with four potential :
D Alembertian A^mu=4*pi j^mu,DAlembertian being an invariant operator and j^mu a four vector. But the solutions for A^mu may or may not be a four vector as discussed in the following paper:https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BymT8iD6LY1nS0wxcjRpTldyamc/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Applying Lorentz gauge in any one inertial frame we obtain the wave equation with four potential :D Alembertian A^mu=4*pi j^mu,The quantity j^mu being a four vector,D Alembertian A^mu behaves like a four vector: D Alembertian A^mu=4*pi j^mu holds for all inertial frames,D Alembertian being an invariant operator.But this is conditioned by the fact that we are assuming the invariance of the Lorentz gauge.If it were not invariant  the wave equation for four potential would not have appeared in the other frames leading to inconsistency.

Comment: (in continuation)Lorentz transformations as well as other transformations could cater to the requirement(discussed in the uploaded paper).Treating four potential as a four vector we can prove the invariance of Lorentz gauge. But starting from Lorentz gauge and using Lorentz gauge exclusively we cannot arrive at Lorentz transformations [transformation of four vectors]

Comment: Since the d'Alembertian involves second derivatives, you can add anything whose second derivative vanishes without changing the result, so the proof is incomplete.  But, it does apply to useful vector potentials.

Comment: Steps of Logic in relation to mt comments and uploaded paper:https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BymT8iD6LY1nV3JCVjN2SGlRbGM/view?usp=sharing

Comment: From an earlier paper:https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BymT8iD6LY1nLV9BNGt6MmpPODA/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Lienard Wiechert Potentials do follow the wave equation [with source] and the Lorentz gauge condition.But they do not constitute a four vector quadruplet:https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BymT8iD6LY1nQl80NHVuSl80cW8/view?usp=sharing